# Formulario de registro mysql php no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy trabajando con un formulario sencillo de registro de usuarios, ya se insertan, el código

**HTML**

```
<?php include '../includes/insert/insert_usuario.php'; ?>    
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Nombre</b></label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="3" name="name">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Correo</b></label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control grey" name="email">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control grey" minlength="5" name="password">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Confirmar contraseña</b></label>
       <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control grey" minlength="5" name="cPassword">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> GUARDAR</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

**PHP (insert_usuario.php)**

```
<?php

  $msg = "";

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'carreteras');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'];

    if ($password != $cPassword)
      $msg = "¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!";
    else {
      $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
      $con->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$hash')");
      $msg = "¡Usuario registrado con éxito!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Tengo dos inconvenientes, el primero es que cuando oprimo submit y las contraseñas no coinciden se limpian los campos en mi formulario, cómo puedo hacer para que esto no ocurra y permitir al usuario editar su información. El segundo, es que si el INSERT procede pasa lo siguiente: se limpian los campos "aparentemente", muestra el mensaje de ¡Usuario registrado con éxito! pero se queda ahí el mensaje y si refresco la página con f5 se vuelve a insertar en mi base de datos el mismo registro, aun que aparentemente se haya limpiado.

Espero puedan ayudarme, les agradezco desde ya.

Comment: que codigo existen en : insert_usuario.php

Comment: Perdón, edité mi pregunta para que sea más clara

Comment: en tu html no tienes ..codigo javascript ?...estas usando algun framework quiza ?

Comment: no se me hizo necesario utilizar javaScript, lo único que hago es imprimir mensajes a través de la variable $msg a través de php, crees que sea conveniente para resolver mi problema, soy nueva en programación

Comment: valida las contraseñas con `js` a si no va ser necesario enviar nada a `php` y podrás mostrar un alert o cualquier label con el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola estimada te propongo las siguientes mejoras:

```
     <?php
     //Para efectos de obtener errores de programación:
      //error_reporting(E_ALL);
       //ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

     //1. Declaración de variables
       $msg = "";
      $name = $email = $password = $cPassword = "";
     $nameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $cPasswordErr = null;
     //Declaramos una bandera para que me permita ejecutar 
     //el SQL en caso pase todas las 
     validaciones
    $valid = true;
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //validamos que los campos no sean vacíos y sean requeridos:
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "El nombre es requerido.";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
        // chequea que el nombre tenga letras y espacios
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameErr = "Solo se permiten letras y espacios.";
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "El correo es requerido.";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // verificar que el correo esté correcto
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Formato no válido.";
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordErr = "La contraseña es obligatoria";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["cPassword"])) {
        $cPasswordErr = "La confirmación de contraseña es obligatoria";
        $valid = false;
    } else {
        $cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'];
    }
    if ($password != $cPassword) {
        $msg = "¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!";
        $valid = false;
    }
    if ($valid) {
        $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'carreteras');
        //Si pasa las validadciones, ejecuta el SQL
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

         $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES ('$name', 
          $email', $hash')";

         if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          $msg = "¡Usuario registrado con éxito!";
           //EN ESTE PUNTO LO DEBES DE REDIRIGIR A OTRA PANTALLA O REFRESCAR 
           // LA PANTALLA
         } else {
           echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
             }

           $con->close();

      }
    }

     function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
        }
        ?>
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
    <html>
       <head>
          <style>
               .error {color: #FF0000;}
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>  

            <form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post" action="<?php echo                  
         htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Nombre</b></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="3" name="name" 
          value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Correo</b></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control grey" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control grey" minlength="5" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b>Confirmar contraseña</b></label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control grey" minlength="5" name="cPassword" value="<?php echo $cPassword; ?>">
                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $cPasswordErr; ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $msg; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> GUARDAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
echo "<h2>Tus entradas:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $password;
echo "<br>";
echo $cPassword;
echo '<br>';
echo $msg;
?>
```

Referencia: [insertar MySQLi](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)  [Manejo de formularios php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

Comment: me funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias!